# Redirect bash stdout+stderr to one file and stderr to another file

Tags: bash, shell, io-redirection, stdout, stderr

I need to redirect ALL output to one file, and in addition redirect stderr to another file. Can this be done easily?

Let's assume my command for the purposes of this example is:

```
php /tmp/doWork.php
```

I can get output to separate files by using:

```
php /tmp/doWork.php 1> /tmp/stdout_file 2> /tmp/stderr_file
```

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30785783/1178671), I attempted:

```
php /tmp/doWork.php &> /tmp/stdboth_file 2> /tmp/stderr_file
```

but this just put stdout and stderr in `/tmp/stdboth_file` and never wrote to `/tmp/stderr_file`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With `zsh` (and `zsh` only) and its `multios` feature:

```
your-cmd 2> stdout+stderr.log >&2 2> stderr.log
```

As fd 2 is redirected twice, `zsh` implements an internal `tee` to have it sent to both files.

With `bash` (or any Bourne-like shell (other than `zsh` where you'd need to disable `multios` for it to work here)), you can do the `tee`ing by hand with:

```
{ your-cmd 2>&1 >&3 3>&- | tee stderr.log 3>&-; } > stderr+stdout.log 3>&1
```

(though you lose the exit status of `your-cmd`. `zsh` has it in `$pipestatus[1]`, `bash` in `"${PIPESTATUS[0]}"` though (provided the redirection into `stderr+stdout.log` didn't fail)).

To record the pid of `your-cmd`, you could do:

```
{ sh -ec 'echo "$$" > /var/run/pidfile; exec your-cmd' 2>&1 >&3 3>&- |
   tee stderr.log 3>&-; } > stderr+stdout.log 3>&1
```

With `yash` and it's *process redirection* feature:

```
your-cmd > stdout+stderr.log 2>(tee stderr.log)
```

(but note that `yash` will not wait for the termination of that `tee` command, so the log files may not be complete by the time you run the next command after that).

Something similar (and with the same caveat) can be done with *process substitution* in `bash`, `zsh` and `ksh93`:

```
{ your-cmd 2> >(tee stderr.log); } > stderr+stdout.log
```

To run in background and get the pid:

```
(exec your-cmd 2> >(tee stderr.log)) > stderr+stdout.log & pid=$!
```

With `rc`:

```
{your-cmd |[2=0] tee stderr.log} > stdout+stderr.log
```

`rc`'s pipes allow specifying which file descriptors are connected to the pipe. With other shells, it's always fd 1 of the left command and fd 0 of the right one (hence the little dance with fd 3 above to shift file descriptors around). `rc` will report failure if either `your-cmd` or `tee` fails, though the exact number may be lost.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'd also like to send the pid of my command to a file and used to append the command with `& echo $! >> /path/to/pidfile`. I can still do this but will the pid be correct, or that of tee etc?

Comment: @LukeCousins, yes in `cmd1 | cmd2 &`, `$!` is the pid of `cmd2`. You can use the process substitution approach in that case. Or you can use `sh -c 'echo "$$" > pidfile; exec your-cmd'` in place of `your-cmd`.

Comment: Ok, in this particular use case the exit status is not important. Could you give an example of using bash with the pid file getting the right id using process substitution as I'm not quite sure. Thanks for all the help :)

Comment: @Luke, see edit. In the process substitution case, in the case of `bash` or `zsh` (as opposed `ksh93`), if you add a `&`, because of the command group, you'll get an extra subshell process, and `$!` will be the pid of that subshell. Hence the extra `exec`.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas In your bash command `{ your-cmd 2>&1 >&3 3>&- | tee stderr.log 3>&-; } > stderr+stdout.log 3>&1` , what does `3>&-` do and why do you need curly braces around the first 2 parts?