# Is there any way, how to accumulate standard and error output into one file and at the same time also extract the error output to a separate file?

Tags: bash, io-redirection

I want to perform some bash script execution and want to capture all outputs into one file. This is easy, with the redirection of file descriptor 2 to the same place like the standard output, writing to file descriptor 1.

But how can I at the same time extract the error output only - additionally - into some special file?

The background is - I want to produce a special error file from the script run in the case there occurred some error, but I also want to see the possible error messages in the context of all output messages, describing, where the error exactly occurred and possibly other debug messages or error context.

I also cannot know in advance, which error messages will be produced during the execution, so I cannot perform some post-processing filtering of the produced complete output for some specific string it some error occurred - I do not know, for which string I should look...

EDIT of the original question, marked as duplicate: The solution for bash

`{ your-cmd 2>&1 >&3 3>&- | tee stderr.log 3>&-; } > stderr+stdout.log 3>&1`

proposed here:

[Redirect bash stdout+stderr to one file and stderr to another file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/364166/redirect-bash-stdoutstderr-to-one-file-and-stderr-to-another-file)

does not work for me. It generates two same files, in the error file is the same content like in the standard output file.

Comment: If that command does not work, then you are doing something wrong.  Test the command in your question with `your-cmd` replaced by `( echo 'stdout'; echo 'stderr' >&2 )`, for example.  If you could mention what command you're trying to plug into that expression (and what the final expression looks like), that would help in trying to figure out why it does not work.

Comment: See also, as an alternative with a straightforward syntax for Bash (that also writes standard error on its own file): https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/580016/315749

Comment: @Kusalananda Thank you very much for your comment. I start following script:

`#!/bin/bash

DATESTR=$(date +%Y%m%d)

FILENAME=/tmp/backup.${DATESTR}

{ ( /usr/bin/pg_dump --host myhost --port 5432 --username "username" --no-password  --format plain --no-owner --inserts --no-privileges --no-tablespaces --verbose --file "${FILENAME}.sql" "mydb" ) 2>&1 >&3 3>&- | tee ${FILENAME}.err 3>&-; } > ${FILENAME}.log 3>&1`

Comment: Note that you get one file with the standard error output, and one with the combined output. If standard error contains all the output there is and there is no output on standard  output, I would expect both files to be the same.