# Redirect stdout and stderr to separate files, and both to third file

Tags: bash, shell-script

So, let's say I have a script like this.

```
log_files=(output_{console,stdout,stderr}.log)
do_stuff 2>"${log_files[2]}" 1>"${log_files[1]}"
```

While the function should redirect stdout to `"${log_files[1]}"` and stderr to `"${log_files[2]}"`, I also want to have both stdout and stderr redirected to `"${log_files[0]}"` at the same time. How can this be done?

Comment: Related: [Redirect bash stdout+stderr to one file and stderr to another file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/364166)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## tee

Recall that `echo "foo" | tee --append log.txt`
asks [tee](https://linux.die.net/man/1/tee)
to send "foo" to both a file and to file descriptor 1.

This puts "foo" in a pair of files:

```
echo "foo" | tee --append one.txt  >> two.txt
```

So you could redirect to a pair of subshells,
each of which records incoming text to a pair of files.

## named pipe

If you require greater flexibility, you could alternatively
create named pipes and then apply arbitrary logic to the results.

```
$ mkfifo /tmp/stdout
$ mkfifo /tmp/stderr
```

Send file descriptors 1 and 2 to those, just as you're already doing.
In another terminal tab, or in a background daemon,
run `tail -f` or its moral equivalent to
retrieve lines of text from each [FIFO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIFO_(computing_and_electronics)) in real time.
Filter with a regex, embellish with timestamps,
do whatever you like, and then write the results
to as many sinks as you desire.

Answer (score 2):

This would be far easier in zsh with `multios` where the shell does some internal magic to send the output to all destinations if there are multiple redirections on the same fd, e.g.:

```
% do_stuff > stdout.log 2> stderr.log &> both.log
```

(note that the ordering between outputs to stdout and stderr could get mixed up because of the intermediate process that handles the duplicate output.)

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, to do this without a named pipe, you could use the answers to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16497317/piping-both-stdout-and-stderr-in-bash

Separately pipe stdout and stderr each to their own copy of tee, both of which append to the same file, and writes to the individual files desired.

However, not all implementations of tee will do this safely, so in some situations, you may end up with oddly interspersed blocks of stdout and stderr in the "both" file.

To the best of my knowledge, tee doesn't have a way to force safe line-based buffering.